# Is there a way to setup 2 frontends in phoenix app?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, elixir, phoenix-framework

In the project I have phoenix web app which serves its own frontend (webpack 5, served on "/")

```
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/",
    from: :myapp_web,
    gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts images js robots.txt favicon.ico)
```

I want to add another frontend (which would be served on /app (this frontend uses API I built). I decided to try adding another frontend as static app, so I configured nuxt to build static files:

```
export default {
  ssr: false,
  target: 'static'
```

in `nuxt.config.js` and configure endpoint properly:

```
 plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/app",
    from: "myapp-app/dist",
    gzip: false
```

this allows to work (but only partialy):

- you can enter the app by opening `localhost:4000/app/index.html` and continue using app (since JS is loading partial views generated by nuxt (and changing url by window.href)
- when entering the app by inputting `localhost:4000/app/posts` in the address bar following file does not exist (which is expected, because html partial generated by nuxt is located under `/posts/index.html`

I want to found a way to fix that problem - by changing paths in Endpoint (when visiting localhost:4000/posts render file from localhost:4000/posts/index.html), however, I don't know how should I do that. I am thinking if this is the right approach and if not how should I proceed?

Comment: If you restructure your app to be an "umbrella" app then you could add the 2nd frontend as an app. Just go to the `apps` directory and `mix phx.new.web my_new_frontend`

Comment: Right, I forgot about it, I think that's the right approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried the following structure for your Nuxt app?

```
pages/
-- posts/
---- index.vue
```

Otherwise, we could look for a [redirect](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module) but I'm curious why `/index` may not be generated here. Do you have all your routes when you `yarn generate`?

Comment: Yes, this works - pages/posts/index.vue is valid static path thus it can render